# Qt access parent from page of stackedWidget created as separate class in QtDesigner

Tags: qt, qt4, qt4.8

Because of some bug in **QtDesigner** integrated into QtCreator 2.4.1 I created separated definition as a class inheriting from *QWidget*. This solve the problem with lying out widgets in Layouts on pages of *QStackedWidget*. Additionally this nicely separate complex UI.

However with this solution I fall into problem of main form and the page being separate classes. In the inner class I do not see elements (widgets, slots) of the main form/window, while the logic requires operations there (enabling/disabling some buttons, binding popups, etc.)

I am looking for a good pattern how such problem should be solved. I tried follow some advices found on Google with accessing through *parent* pointer, however I failed and crashed the application :-) This is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typical Qt-way of solving such a problem is done via [signals](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html).

In your case you can emit signals with some data from page, while main form has an associated function(-s) connected to the object signals.
Something like:

*Definition*

```
class page : public QObject
{
     Q_OBJECT

...

    signals:
        void my_custom_signal(int value);
};
```

*Implementation*

```
void page::function()
{
    // some code

    emit my_custom_signal(FORM_SHOW_ABOUT_DIALOG);
}
```